# Protobuf-net error serialising collection of enums values

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DayOfWeek Bar { get; set; }
}
```

(where DayOfWeek is the enum System.DayOfWeek).

I can serialise it with protobuf-net using this code:

```
RuntimeTypeModel runtimeTypeModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

MetaType metaType = runtimeTypeModel.Add(typeof(Foo), false);

ValueMember valueMember = metaType.AddField(1, "Bar");

TypeModel model = runtimeTypeModel.Compile();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    model.Serialize(ms, foo);
}
```

If I change Foo to this it also works:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IReadOnlyList<int> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If I change it to this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IReadOnlyList<DayOfWeek> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I get: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No serializer for type System.DayOfWeek is available for model CompiledModel_c9ca355e-e813-4c8e-afb2-686b213506bb'

It works if I mark up Foo with attributes, but *I don't want to do that*, so is there any way of getting this to serialise working directly with the model in code?

FURTHER INFO:

If I change Foo to:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DayOfWeek Bar { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<DayOfWeek> Baz { get; set; }
}
```

And the serialising code to:

```
metaType.AddField(1, "Bar");
metaType.AddField(2, "Baz");
```

It still fails on *Baz*, even though it knows about DayOfWeek for *Bar*, which seems odd

FINALLY:

OK, so if I do this it works:

```
runtimeTypeModel.Add(typeof(DayOfWeek), false);
```

Which is OK, but I'm still interested in why it handles an enum value automatically in some circumstances, but not in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug, so there isn't really anything to change in your code - it is a library problem; probably quite a simple one to resolve. It is probably best reported on GitHub.

Comment: I have added an issue on GitHub... thanks